# Druid query to get "latest" value from third column

Tags: druid, apache-calcite

I have a table in Druid, something like

```
Timestamp || UserId || Action
```

And I need to get the latest Action for each UserId. In MySQL I would do something like

```
Select * from users u1 inner join (
    select UserId, max(Timestamp) as maxt from users group by UserId
) u2
on u1.UserId = u2.UserId and u1.Timestamp = u2.maxt
```

But Druid can't do joins and only very basic sub-selects.

I know the "right" answer is probably to denormalize the data at ingestion time, but unfortunately that's not an option as I don't "own" the ingestion part.

The only solution I have come up with so far is to retrieve all the results for both queries in Java code and do the join manually, but I will run into memory constraints when the dataset grows I would imagine.

I tried to look at materialized views, but that looks like it's still incubating and would require a hadoop cluster, so isn't really viable.

I tried to do something like

```
Select * from users u1 where concat(Timestamp, UserId) in (
    select concat(UserId, max(Timestamp)) from users group by UserId
)
```

But it didn't like that either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> LATEST(expr)
>
> Returns the latest value of `expr`, which must be numeric. If `expr`
> comes from a relation with a timestamp column (like a Druid
> datasource) then "latest" is the value last encountered with the
> maximum overall timestamp of all values being aggregated. If `expr`
> does not come from a relation with a timestamp, then it is simply the
> last value encountered.

https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.20.0/querying/sql.html